# anchor animation scroll is not accurate

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor

I happen to have placed at strategic locations to access anchors scroll through the site. It does an animation jquery but most of the time or falls short or passed the place, do not know because it is not 100% accurate on the site, what could be happening?

**jquery:**

```
$(function(){

     $('a[href*=#]').click(function() {

     if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'')
         && location.hostname == this.hostname) {

             var $target = $(this.hash);

             $target = $target.length && $target || $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');

             if ($target.length) {

                 var targetOffset = $target.offset().top;

                 $('html,body').animate({scrollTop: targetOffset}, 1000);

                 return false;

            }

       }

   });

});
```

**buttons:**

```
<a id="ancla-1" href="#ancla-1">

<a name="ancla-1"></a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I found the problem, I put it here in case someone can earn him the solution.

The page loads so fast that did not take into account the space that used the header. The solution has been to apply a timer that takes a second to activate the scroll of the page.

Maybe it's not a very elegant solution but this way never fails.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

setTimeout(function () {
    var anchor = window.location.hash.substring(1);

if(anchor!="" || anchor!="AB"){

    var newAnchor= "#anchor-" +anchor;

    $(newAnchor).trigger("click");

}

    }, 1000);


});
```